# Dividing numbers in java gives zero values

Tags: java

I have simple code to test please check the following. why my code did not return expected result.

```
public class test {

public static void main(final String a[]) {
    final double d1 = 1 / 1000; // should be 0.001
    final double d2 = 2 / 20; // should be  0.1
    System.out.println(d1 + "--" + d2); // 0.0--0.0
 }
}
```

Comment: You are making integer divisions that are cast to `double` after the divisions are completed.

Comment: How many identical answers do we need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're dividing integers, thus producing integers, `0`, which are stored as `0.0`.

Use this :

```
final double d1 = 1d / 1000; // divide a double by an integer -> get a double
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        final double d1 = 1d / 1000; // 0.001
        final double d2 = 2d / 20; // 0.1
        System.out.println(d1 + "--" + d2); // 0.001--0.1
     }
```

where The `"d"` is supposed to be used for quick conversions to double.

Remember that actually you need to convert both of them.
But one if one of them is double, the other will be implicitly converted.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing integer division instead of double division.

Change, for example, to:

```
public class test {

public static void main(final String a[]) {
    final double d1 = 1.0 / 1000.0; // 0.001
    final double d2 = 2.0 / 20.0; // 0.1
    System.out.println(d1 + "--" + d2); // 0.0--0.0
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   final double d1 = (double)1 / 1000; // 0.001
    final double d2 = (double)2 / 20; // 0.1
    System.out.println(d1 + "--" + d2); // 0.0--0.0
```

**Reason:**

1 and 100, both are integers. So 1/100 will be definitely an integer. So although the theoretical value is 0.001 but as it will return an integer so it will return 0. So you need to cast one value to double. or use like dystroy suggested

Comment: someone dowvoted all except ... dystroy.. strange !! ... downvoter please correct us if we are wrong

Comment: If you're wondering if I downvoted, then the answer is no. I suppose you were downvoted because identical answers aren't really useful but in this case of a simple question, as I perfectly know you didn't copy but already know the answer, I don't see a point in downvoting. EDIT : I just downvoted, right now, the two last answers, coming long after and really really useless (one of the answerers even mentionned a "bandwagon").

Comment: @dystroy .. no I didn't think you downvoted really.. I respect your reputation and definitely such reputation can only be  earned by experts... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test {

public static void main(final String a[]) {
    final double d1 = 1d / 1000d; // 0.001
    final double d2 = 2d / 20d; // 0.1
    System.out.println(d1 + "--" + d2); // 0.0--0.0
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static void main(final String a[]) {
    final double d1 = 1 / 1000d; // 0.001
    final double d2 = 2 / 20d; // 0.1
    System.out.println(d1 + "--" + d2); // 0.0--0.0
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Ooh, a bandwagon!

You're doing integer division, in case you couldn't tell by any of the other six posts telling you the same thing.

Comment: *"Ooh, a bandwagon!"* ? Seriously, you come long after the first answers, why bother to add this duplicate answer ?